# How to cache profile picture from Google plus in android

Tags: android, google-plus

I am trying to set the Google plus profile image. I am able to get the URL and set the image using:

```
    private class LoadProfileImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public LoadProfileImage(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    Protected Bitmap doInBackground (String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
  }
```

But this doesn't work when there is NO internet. The profile image is always getting it from the URL specified.

The question is: How do I cache the profile image? Or shall I store this in shared Preference? This will be useful whenever there is no internet I still have profile image...

Let me know!

Thanks!!

Comment: Maybe you can use this https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader
It's supporting cache

Answer (score 0):

If there is no internet connection , you can may or may not get the profile image,its depends .

> What you can do in this case ?

1:Simply get the image when internet connection is alive and cache that image in your application cache dir or somewhere else and use it when no internet connection.

2:If that person exist in your contact directory and device owner made a sync with Google+ then can you can try to get that profile pic using that person's email id. `Content provider` allow you fetch the contact detail.

Comment: So how do I cache the image?

Comment: @TheDevMan you can get contact image from here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.html

Comment: @TheDevMan as i mentioned point 1 , you have download and store in cache or somewhere else directory

Comment: I managed to store the URL image using SharedPreference but question here is how long is the data stored in the sharedPreference? Is it similar to MySQL database?

Comment: If you make "clear data" from your application manager then it'll clear sharedpreferences & sqlitedatabase as well. So it will stay longer till you clear app data. It think this is not the best way to do so.